# How can I launch pudb with IPython's post-mortem %debug?

Tags: python, ipython, pudb

I just [got started](https://documen.tician.de/pudb/starting.html) using `breakpoint()` and `pudb`, which is awesome. Now how do I make IPython's `%debug` magic launch pudb?

Note: The pudb [docs](https://documen.tician.de/pudb/index.html?highlight=mortem) say "A post-mortem mode makes it easy to retrace a crashing program’s last steps." On the other hand the (old) [wiki](https://wiki.tiker.net/PuDB/IPythonIntegration) suggests it's not possible.

Comment: [Answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785512/how-to-change-ipython-pdb-and-debug-debugger/72210309#72210309), but when I tried the approach with pudb, it seemed to fail as it tried to grab the traceback using [gc.get_referrers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers). Didn't delve too much deeper on whether there's a simple fix. (Also the wiki link in the question was broken, so maybe this result is something already expected).