# How to change IPython %pdb and %debug debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

By default, ipython uses ipdb as debugger with %pdb or %debug magics.
However, I much prefer pdb++... Is there a way of changing the debugger called with these magics ? (I am aware I can simply use pdb.xpm() on exception with pdb++, but I'd like to make it work with ipython magic commands so that I don't have to wrap the code each time...)

Comment: I have asked a related, unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59874136

Answer (score 2):

So at least for limited circumstances and not in a way I'd necessarily recommend, the answer here is yes. I can't promise the below will work outside the confines of what I did, but it might give you enough insight to play around with it yourself. Caution is warranted because it involves changing undocumented attributes of the `ipython` shell class at runtime. TLDR: I hunted down how `ipython` calls the debugger when the `%pdb` magic is on or when you call the `%debug` magic, and I updated it to use the debugger I wanted. Skip the next two paragraphs if you just want the approach that worked for me and don't care about the hunt.

Long version: when you run `ipython` it starts an instance of [`TerminalInteractiveShell`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py), which has a `debugger_cls` attribute telling you the debugger that `ipython` will launch. Unfortunately, at the level of `TerminalInteractiveShell`, `debugger_cls` is actually a property of the class, and has no setter that lets you modify it. Rather, it either gets set to `Pdb` (actually a more featureful `ipython` `Pdb` than the traditional `pdb`) or `TerminalPdb` (even more features).

If you dig deeper, however, you find that `debugger_cls` gets passed up to [`InteractiveShell`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1089) to initialize how tracebacks are handled. There it seems to disappear into the initialization of `InteractiveShell`'s `InteractiveTB` property, but actually just ends up as the `debugger_cls` attribute of that (`InteractiveTB`) class (by setting the inherited attribute from [`TBTools`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/ultratb.py#L204)). Finally, this `debugger_cls` attribute only gets used to set the `pdb` attribute (more or less by doing `TBToolsInstance.pdb = TBToolsInstance.debugger_cls()`) in one of several places. In any case, it turns out that *these* attributes *can* be changed! And if you change them correctly they will percolate to the shell itself! Importantly, this relies on the fact that `ipython` makes use of the [Traitlets](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) package to create a `Singleton` object for the shell, and this allows you to gain access to that object from within the terminal itself. More on that below.

Below I show the code you can run in the `ipython` shell to achieve your desired result. As an example, I'm replacing the default debugger (`TerminalPdb`) with a modified version I created that deals more nicely with certain list comprehensions ([`LcTerminalPdb`](https://github.com/emiliosalazar/LcTerminalPdb)). The process (which you can run in the `ipython` shell) is as follows.

```
# import the TerminalInteractiveShell class
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
# grab the specific instance of the already initialized ipython
shl = TerminalInteractiveShell().instance()
# grab the InteractiveTB attribute (which is a class)
tbClass = shl.InteractiveTB
# load the debugger class you want to use; I assume it's accessible on your path
from LcTerminalPdb import LcTerminalPdb
# change tbClass's debugger_cls to the debugger you want (for consistency 
# with the next line)
tbClass.debugger_cls = LcTerminalPdb
# more importantly, set the pdb attribute to an instance of the class
tbClass.pdb = tbClass.debugger_cls()
# The above line is necessary if you already have the terminal running 
# (and have entered pdb at least once); otherwise, ipython will run it on 
# its own
```

That's it! Note that because you call the `instance()` method of `TerminalInteractiveShell`, you are grabbing the object for the currently running shell, which is why the modifications will affect the shell itself and so all following debugs. For a bonus, you can add these lines of code to your [`ipython_config.py`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html) file, so the debugger you want (`LcTerminalPdb` here) is always loaded with `ipython`:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
'%pdb on',
'from LcTerminalPdb import LcTerminalPdb',
'from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell',
'shl = TerminalInteractiveShell().instance().InteractiveTB',
'shl.debugger_cls = LcTerminalPdb',
]
```

Note that above I don't need to write the extra `shl.pdb = shl.debugger_cls()` line, as `ipython` will take care of it the first time a debug point is entered. But feel free to, to be sure.

NOTES:

- I have only tested this using `LcTerminalPdb`, and only briefly, but it seems to work appropriately
- I suspect as long as other `pdb` debuggers have the same API as `pdb` (i.e. if they can be used by the [`PYTHONBREAKPOINT`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0553/) environment variable) then it should work
- It's really unclear to me whether changing such deep attributes will have unexpected effects, so not sure how much I recommend this approach